# How do you actually use LaTeX conversion systems like make4ht and tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, overleaf, html, make4ht, ebook

I have acquainted myself with the export methods of LaTeX but I am utterly confounded by how I am supposed to actually utilize conversion software created by others out in the web. I understand the basics of running command lines but I have no sense of how I am supposed to have my .tex files get run through a converter absent any actual program.

I am not a Linux user and my end goal is to convert work I am doing in Overleaf into an ebook. I am sure once I can actually get the files into the software that I can figure out the rest, but can someone really just walk me through how I'm supposed to get something like tex4ht to work to begin with?

Comment: If you don't have TeX distribution on your system, but use only Overleaf, you can use this method: https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html

Comment: if you do have a locally installed latex, basically instead of typing `pdflatex document` to get a PDF you type `htlatex document` to get an HTML. There are of course customisations and complications, but basically that's it.

Comment: A conversion probably worth from simple to complex formats, but probably will be a pain in the opposite direction. If the final format is not just the PDF, consider work with a simpler markup language as markdown, and convert from markdown to LaTeX if you need print the document or a PDF version.